# Custom tag using the Cffunction Tag

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to create a custom tag for cffunction for trying to reuse and not write cffunction again and again, I am using the following as:

```
<cffunction access="#attributes.access#" returntype="#attributes.return#" output="#attributes.output#" name="#attributes.method#">
```

but cfbuilder version 2 is giving me illegal attribute error, i am not sure, it is right or wrong, can i do like this

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain how this will help you not write cffunction tags?

Comment: I just want to pass few parameters to make the simple functions use this, I will pass it the things like this:

Comment: `<cf_functions methodname="savemailserver" procedurename="spx_gs_mailserver_create" collection="#form#">`. The function has already the cftry and cfcatch blocks hardcoded and transaction also, so as to not to rewrite.

Comment: i think this will not work: cf is throwing me an error like: `Message This expression must have a constant value.`

Comment: It won't work, but it's also a poor idea. Set up a code snippet (or whatever they're called in cfbuilder) that has the gist of what you need.

Comment: yeah, Thanks Matt, i think i will create a snippet in cfbuilder for this

Comment: as a side coldfusion should this knd of functionality and even it sould the dynamic values in the cfcase statements too

Comment: If you think you are writing cffunction too often, maybe you are writing them in the wrong place.

Comment: "as a side coldfusion should this knd of functionality". Well... I don't know that it should, really. You're kinda misunderstanding how functions are supposed to work. There's absolutely no need that I can think of for actually wanting to achieve what you're trying to do here via the approach you're taking. That said... there's no reason these days why case statements oughtn't take a dynamic value; indeed Lucee already allows this in CFML.

Comment: @guys, you misunderstood me, I am just trying to do something where i need not rewrite some piece of code again and again and use it once and for all, but i like Matt's idea of creating a snippet in cfbuilder, Makes sense. as far as other things said; I know cffunction and how it works, was just trying if something like this is a possibility or not.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use  dynamic values (variables) in attributes of `<cffunction>`. Functions are pre-compiled and thus do not allow evaluation at runtime.

If your reason to wrap all functions is to catch errors, there are better approaches to do so, e.g. the `onError` handler.